# How to create a random matrix with certain range in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to create a random matrix within range -10 to 10, which contains decimal, something like:

```
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,]  -0.460297  2.292227  6.241029 -8.023297  -4.400127
[2,]   5.410664  7.410564  0.410664 -2.410664   0.410984
[3,]  -3.066257  2.066257  8.061231  9.066901  -1.062414
```

I've tried

```
random <- matrix(runif(3,min=min(-10),max=max(10)),3,5)
```

but it returns the same value for each row. What should I do to get random value? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need `matrix(runif(15,min= -10,max= 10),3,5)`

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!@akrun

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the min/max functions around the limits and you simply need to create 15 random numbers instead of 3.

```
random <- matrix(runif(15, min=-10, max=10), 3, 5)
```